# Loading plugin text domain before registering post type

Tags: custom-post-types, actions, textdomain

I'm building a wordpress plugin, that will register a post type. Im trying to set up a simple test case where all it does is registering a post type with get text functions and translating it with poedit. I have successfully created the .po and .mo files, and loaded them with the following code:

```
add_action('init', 'client_functions_textdomain');
function client_functions_textdomain(){
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'client-functions', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
```

If i test a gettextcall right after loading this, everything translates fine. And the load_plugin_textdomain() returns true.

But when i afterwards try to register a post type with the following code (taken from the codex), its doesn't translate:

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'client-functions' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'client-functions' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'client-functions' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'client-functions' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'client-functions' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'client-functions' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'client-functions' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'client-functions' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'client-functions' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'client-functions' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'client-functions' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'client-functions' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'client-functions' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'client-functions' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => _x( 'book', 'URL slug', 'client-functions' ) ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

I suspect that this has to do with the fact that both are hooked into the 'init' action, and the registering happens before the text domain is loaded? I have tried the following with no success:

- added priority 0 to the textdoamin action, and priority 20 to book_init function
- i have loaded the text domain in the 'plugins_loaded' action

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks 
Malthe

Comment: Turns out that all the __() and _e() functions loads fine - but not the _x() functions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to add some special function sniffing in the configuration of the pot file (from http://www.cssigniter.com/ignite/wordpress-poedit-translation-secrets/):

```
__
_e
__ngettext:1,2
_n:1,2
__ngettext_noop:1,2
_n_noop:1,2
_c
_nc:4c,1,2
_x:1,2c
_nx:4c,1,2
_nx_noop:4c,1,2
_ex:1,2c
esc_attr__
esc_attr_e
esc_attr_x:1,2c
esc_html__
esc_html_e
esc_html_x:1,2c
```